# RxDB RxCollectionCreator Typescript Error

Tags: typescript, rxjs, electron

This is my first time using RxDB and I've encountered a weird Typescript error.

The relevant parts of my Electron project are as follows:

```
import RxDB, { RxCollection, RxDatabase } from "rxdb";
RxDB.plugin(require("pouchdb-adapter-idb"));

// Took this from the Electron example on Github so I knew I had a valid JSONSchema
const heroSchema = {
  title: 'hero schema',
  description: 'describes a simple hero',
  version: 0,
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      primary: true
    },
    color: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  },
  required: ['color']
};

// These lines are actually in an async function so the await keyword is not an issue
const db = await RxDB.create({ name: "heroedb", adapter: "idb" });

const devices = await db.collection({
     name: "herocollection",
     schema: heroSchema
});
```

But Typescript complains:

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; schema: { title: string; description: string; version: number; type: string; prop...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RxCollectionCreator'.
Types of property 'schema' are incompatible.
Type '{ title: string; description: string; version: number; type: string; properties: { name: { type: ...' is not assignable to type 'RxJsonSchema | RxSchema<any>'.
Type '{ title: string; description: string; version: number; type: string; properties: { name: { type: ...' is not assignable to type 'RxSchema<any>'.
Property 'jsonID' is missing in type '{ title: string; description: string; version: number; type: string; properties: { name: { type: ...'
```

If I add `jsonID` to my schema it just complains about another missing property, and another, and another. Obviously, I have done something wrong. Any wisdom on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the types definitions https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb/blob/master/src/typings/rx-schema.d.ts, scema may be of type RxJsonSchema or RxSchema, not sure what is missing or anything extra

Comment: @DennisR Interesting. If I set `heroSchema = RxSchema.create({...})` the error goes away. I wonder why the other way doesn't work because that's how it shows in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RxDB source code can be found [here](https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb/tree/master/src).
When you use RxSchema.create({...}) function it actually  creates instance of the class RxSchema, so type will definitely match.
Otherwise interface for collection creator is the following:

```
export interface RxCollectionCreator {
    name: string;
    schema: RxJsonSchema | RxSchema;
    pouchSettings?: PouchSettings;
    migrationStrategies?: {
        [key: number]: Function
    };
    autoMigrate?: boolean;
    statics?: {
        [key: string]: Function
    };
    methods?: {
        [key: string]: Function
    };
    attachments?: {
        [key: string]: Function
    };
    options?: any;
}
```

And the schema interface is either RxJsonSchema or RxSchema.
See also examples in the source code.
You object seems to mach RxJsonSchema type definition, however either some literal from the interface is missing or there is some extra that TypeScript complains about.

```
export declare class RxJsonSchema {
    title?: string;
    description?: string;
    version: number;
    type: 'object';
    properties: { [key: string]: RxJsonSchemaTopLevel };
    required?: Array<string>;
    compoundIndexes?: Array<string | Array<string>>;
    disableKeyCompression?: boolean;
    additionalProperties?: true;
    attachments?: {
            encrypted?: boolean
    };
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I have no idea what is missing/extra and the Typescript error seems completely useless. The code I have posted is the exact code that is emitting the error (except the `await` calls are wrapped in an async function). Can you see what I have missed? I have looked over the type definitions many times now and I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think I'll just stick with `RxSchema.create({...})` for now. I've been in contact with the creator and he's stumped as well.